# VBA using ahtCommonOpenFileSave with ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT, error when selecting single file

Tags: vba, ms-access

Maybe I'm overlooking the obvious, but I cant figure out how to deal with a single result in an array.

I'm using [Ken Getz ahtCommonFileOpenSave API](http://access.mvps.org/access/api/api0001.htm) in VBA to enable selecting multiple files, using the following code.

```
Private Sub btn_openfiles_Click()
    Dim strFilter As String
    Dim strInputFileName As String
    Dim strFiles() As String
    Dim a As Long

    strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Images (*.PNG)", "*.PNG")

    strFiles = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                        Filter:=strFilter, _
                        OpenFile:=True, _
                        InitialDir:="T:\DTP\Programs\Default\", _
                        DialogTitle:="Please select an input file...", _
                        Flags:=ahtOFN_EXPLORER + ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT)
    If IsArray(strFiles) Then
        For a = 0 To UBound(strFiles)
            Me.test_filenames = Me.test_filenames & strFiles(a) & vbCrLf
        Next a
    Else
        Me.test_filenames = strFiles
    End If

End Sub
```

I know that the result is an array, because I'm setting the ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT flag. When multiple files are selected, this goes well. But if only one file is selected, an

> error 13 is thrown (type mismatch on strFiles)

because the return value of ahtCommonFileOpenSave is not an array.
I may be able to force an Array type just by adding a dummy value to the array produced by  ahtCommonFileOpenSave and disregard this when processing the file names in the form, but maybe there is a better solution. Anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Change `Dim strFiles() As String` to `Dim strFiles`.  this function returns a string if one files is selected, and an array if more than 1 file is selected.

Comment: Another suggestion, look at: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SYfdkdkkFRE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I already mentioned, overlooking the obvious. Changing the variable type into variant did the trick . ahtComminFileOpenSave returns the complete array when multiple files are selected and is always a Variant type. Luuk's suggestion works too (a variant type is used by default when the variable type is omitted). 
The corrected (and amended) code is like this and works like a charm!

```
Private Sub btn_openfiles_Click()
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strInputFileName As String
Dim varFiles As Variant
Dim a As Long

strFilter = ahtAddFilterItem(strFilter, "Images (*.PNG)", "*.PNG")
Me.test_filenames = ""

varFiles = ahtCommonFileOpenSave( _
                    Filter:=strFilter, _
                    OpenFile:=True, _
                    InitialDir:="T:\DTP\Programs\Default\", _
                    DialogTitle:="Please select an input file...", _
                    Flags:=ahtOFN_EXPLORER + ahtOFN_ALLOWMULTISELECT)

If IsArray(varFiles) Then
    For a = 0 To UBound(varFiles)
        Me.test_filenames = Me.test_filenames & varFiles(a) & vbCrLf
    Next a
Else
    Me.test_filenames = varFiles
End If
```

End Sub